# Simple onchange post submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following form:

```
    <form id="MainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php"> 
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="upload" onchange="document.getElementById('MainForm').submit();" title="Go!" accept="image/*">
    </form>
```

And in the beginning of the same page, in the php:

```
 if(isset($_POST['file']))
 {     
     echo 'ok'; // and do stuff latter
 }
```

The idea is to send the file when I select it, without having to press any kind of submit button, but its not echoing ok.
When I change my form method to get, and put $_GET instead of $_POST it echoes ok, but I need to do it with post and I couldn't figure out what I'm missing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```html
   <?php  if($_FILES['file']['size']>0){     
 echo 'ok'; // and do stuff latter
 }else{
?>

 <form id="MainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#"> 
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="upload" onchange="document.getElementById('MainForm').submit();" title="Go!" accept="image/*">
</form>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: had the wrong name in the $_FILES var, edited now, sorry

Comment: I got some minor problems but I guess I can work my way around them. This seems to be the right way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

SORRY, I pasted something wrong in there without rechecking it - that made no sense. I edited it now, hopefully should make more sense...

if this `if(isset($_POST['file']))`is on the *same* page, it's referring to something that comes from a *previous* page, so posting something on *that* page and referring to it on the same page won't work

Comment: I'm actually handling all my requests like that, on the same page   'if(isset($_POST['submit ']' { do stuff } . Everything is working fine but this one. Am I handling all the posts wrongly?